# Glassfish application URL with ID

Tags: url, web-applications, deployment, glassfish

I am trying to deploy an application in Glassfish 5.0
Everything goes well, except, my application URL is appended with some sort of ID.
E.g.: It should be like this: http://localhost:8080/AppName/
But it is like this: http://localhost:8080/AppName1016016594088618765/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem, added the context-root tag to my glassfish-web.xml file like this and now it works:

```
<glassfish-web-app>
<context-root>AppName</context-root> 
</glassfish-web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is the glassfish-web.xml file in your application or glassfish configuration?

Comment: Answering my own question above: the file goes in the WEB-INF folder of the application. Thanks again @JDJ56